# EFCore - Unusual Parent / Child Entity Configuration Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Trying to configure EFCore to model a "parent - child" relationship.

In our implementation, a user can have zero or more "Guest" users, and each "Guest" user has exactly 1 "Parent" user. None of these relationships are modeled on the `[User]` table, but through the `[GuestUser]` table.

The model uses an existing MSSQL database schema that looks roughly like this:

```
[User]
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY

[GuestUser]
   [GuestUserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
   [ParentUserId] INT NOT NULL
```

`[UserId]` and `[ParentUserId]` are FK references to `[User].[UserId]`

The `User` entity is declared as

```
public class User 
{
   public int UserId {get; set;}

   public virtual User ParentUser {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<User> GuestUsers {get;set;}
}
```

`ParentUser` will be `null` except when the current instance is a "guest user". Likewise, `GuestUsers` will be empty unless the current instance is a "parent user".

This is the `GuestUser` entity as we currently have it modeled (though I don't really want or need the `User` and `GuestUser` properties):

```
public class GuestUser
{
    public int GuestUserId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User ParentUser { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm having a hard time configuring the relationship in my DbContext because I can't use `.UsingEntity()` when defining the relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(b =>
{
   b.HasOne(u => u.ParentUser)
    .WithMany(u => u.GuestUsers)
    .UsingEntity(?????)              <-- Error, not available
}
```

Somehow the relationship has to go through the `GuestUser` table, I know, but I'm stumped as to how to do that.

If it were a many-to-many relationship, I know I could use `.UsingEntity()` to define the both sides of the relationship as well as the join table. I've also tried various ways to configured `GuestUser` but none of those seem to help either.

Am I missing something obvious or is this not a relationship that EFCore can model cleanly?

Comment: `GuestUsers` should be `ICollection<GuestUser>`.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid - GuestUsers is essentially a "join" entity.

Comment: Yes, but there is no skip navigation feature possible here. You have to access the users through GuestUsers, no other option.

Comment: @GertArnold it's certainly doable in a many-to-many relationship (such as Users => UserRoles => Roles - we have a `User.Roles` property that doesn't require us to go through `UserRoles`).

Comment: Yeah, but you say you don't want that. Effectively the relationship you have is 1:n. Skip navigation is not supported for 1:n because it's not main line to have a junction record in 1:n.